# Git will not commit files created by Composer in Drupal

Tags: git, composer-php, drupal-8, drush

I have installed a Drupal Module using Composer.
when I add and commit using Git, the folder is committed, but no contents.
Here is the output of git commit

```
 create mode 160000 modules/contrib/backup_migrate
```

Here are the permissions on that folder

```
drwxrwxr-x
```

When I install the Module using Drush, Git commits the Folder and Contents, no problem.
The permissions are identical for Drush and Composer Installs. The output of the Git Commit is:

```
create mode 100644 modules/contrib/backup_migrate/.gitignore
```

and lots more following.
I have had a good look here on StackOverflow and elsewhere, but no-one seems to be able to solve this particular problem.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your issue is, but git will *not* commit empty directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the problem.
The directory has plenty of files and folders in it, but it also has a .git repository hidden away thanks to Composer.
I removed the .git repository from the module folder and that cured the problem.
Clearly you cannot have any Git repos as sub-repos.
I can now commit the new module and push to origin.